# Link to form submissions

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I have a section named Contest.
In there, you can choose a Solspace Freeform using its fieldtype.
I am using the `cp.entries.right-pane` hook to show the editor the number of submission directly in the Contest edit view.

I want to put a link : "Show submissions"
How can I (pre) filter the submissions for a given form knowing that Solspace  dosen't have a route for this and uses only JS ?

Comment: Is this for the control panel or a template on the front-end?